# Speed Dial Icon in UC browser

Tags: opera, apple-touch-icon

in Opera, the tag  `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="....">` is displayed in speed dial, but How can I set image in my website to show in speed dial of **UC browser** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible. UC browser seems to always use a default picture for Speed dial and Home screen.

I have run the [compatibility test of RealFaviconGenerator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility_test), which uses almost all known techniques to get a favicon: `favicon.ico` file, PNG icons, Apple Touch icon, Windows 8 tiles with and without `browserconfig.xml`... If UC browser was able to accept a favicon, the test should have succeeded but it didn't. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.