# Define Speed Dial image from my website

Tags: opera

The title pretty much sums up the problem - I have a website and I would like to specify an image that should be shown in the speed dial when a user adds my site to his speed dial. I can see that when I add for example Gmail or Facebook, they both have a specific image whereas my site is just shown on random color background with my domain name as a text.

**So is it possible to specify Opera Speed Dial image in HTML using some meta tag?**

Thanks

PS. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269899/speed-dial-icon-in-uc-browser), however, it's over a year old.

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

**No.** However, you can suggest an image to the user to use, but even then the speed dial will offer thumbnails of your site before any icons.

### Long answer

Each time you see an entry on your speed dial page that's displayed as text, the domain of that site is checked against Opera's Speed Dial server at `speeddials.opera.com`.

The format of the API call is `https://speeddials.opera.com/api/v1/thumbnails/some.domain.name`. This call will either return a `HTTP 200 OK` response containing a PNG image (264px wide by 168px tall) or return a `HTTP 404 File Not Found` response with no content.

It is likely that the Opera team monitor the calls to this server and when a particular domain hits "critical mass" they partner with that company (this is only a hypothesis).

### What you can do

When a user bookmarks your website, they can edit the bookmark and select an image for your website. Like [@Angel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2026317) had in their response, you can link in an appropriate image using a link element with `rel="icon"`. An image linked in this way is then suggested to the user.

I personally have found great success in linking a PNG image with dimensions 264x168px with the below declaration *following* the normal icon declarations:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="264x168" href="/path/to/speeddial.png">
```

The `sizes` attribute is included to aid user-agents/browsers in locating the right icon image for their platform without having to download each one. This should minimize fetches of this image by other browsers.

Comment: I will add that this is accurate at the time of writing and subject to change in later editions of Opera.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you can add this link to your html head:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="144x144" href="ico/favicon.png">
```